# XTerm -e option with callback

Tags: xterm, i3

If I execute a program using the `-e` option for `xterm` and close this program, then `xterm` closed as well, e.g.

```
xterm -hold -e "nano"
```

The window (i3wm) is still there but it's empty and I'm not able to do any inputs. How to run xterm like in the example above with a additional requirement, a callback for xterm if I closed nano?

What I can do is:

```
xterm -hold -e "nano;bash"
```

But I don't understand, why I have to start a shell like bash again. I thought `xterm` already should run a shell.

Comment: Why are you using `-hold` in the first place? `-hold` means "don't destroy the window, wait for the window manager to do it", and that's exactly what happens. If you want to start a new xterm with a login shell, why don't you use just `xterm`? Or do you want to start a login shell, and execute a command within this shell, and then continue to use the shell?

Comment: @dirkt, your second guess, is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xterm -hold -e cmd` will run `cmd` in a new `xterm` window and then keep the window displayed after the command has exited (it would normally close the window).

If you want an interactive shell in the window after running an initial command, then

```
xterm -e 'cmd; bash'
```

will do this.  There's no need for `-hold` as the window doesn't close until the shell session exits.

`xterm` can be used to run any program. By default it runs a shell, but with `-e` you change this default behaviour. `xterm -e mutt`, for example, would run the email reader `mutt` *instead of* a shell.