# Start Xterm + run command + keep open and interactive

Tags: bash, xterm

I'm autostarting (from i3wm) an xterm and running a simple command

```
exec xterm -hold -e "echo hello"
```

how do I keep the xterm interactive?

relevant posts:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/928536/script-to-open-terminal-run-command-and-keep-terminal-open

ty

Answer (score 0):

ok I found it

> exec xterm -e "echo hello; bash"

[XTerm -e option with callback](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364052/xterm-e-option-with-callback)