# How do I run gnome-terminal passing in arguments to a command and keeping the command window open and interactive

Tags: shell-script, gnome-terminal

This works with xterm (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/739977/119816)

```
xterm -e "echo hello; bash"
```

but doesn't with `gnome-terminal`.  What is the equivalent way of doing this with `gnome-terminal`?

```
gnome-terminal -- "echo hello; bash"
```

Gives this error:
[image]

I've tried various ways of quoting but no success.  Some tries are:

```
gnome-terminal -- "bash -c \"echo hello; bash\""
#
gnome-terminal -- /usr/bin/bash  /tmp/echo-hi
```

Where `/tmp/echo-hi` is a shell script that echos hi.

And several other variations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash -c` should not be in the quotation.

Try the following:

```
gnome-terminal -- bash -c "echo hello; bash"
```

I am using this one for example:

```
gnome-terminal --window --title "neovim" -- sh -c "nvim"
```

This just executes the `nvim` binary with `sh` in a new gnome-terminal window with the title "neovim". In my case `sh` is just a link to the `bash` binary. So you can basically use any shell binary you want here.

Comment: I see you are brand new to StackOverflow's community.  Welcome and thanks for the answer.  Feel free to incorporate my answer into yours and then I'll delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
gnome-terminal -- bash -c "echo hello; exec bash"
```

The key points are:

1. GNOME uses `--` double dashes to separate the GNOME terminal arguments from the command to run.
2. To run multiple commands you need to run `bash -c`.  By passing in `echo hello; exec bash` causes **hello** to be output and then the original bash to be replaced with a new one that will become your interactive teriminal.